# python. pass function with some parameters specified

Tags: python

I need pass function to another function with some parameters specified.
So half of parameters I need assign before passing function and other parameters would be given inside another function. How to do that?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little better, maybe give some example code? I'm a little confused about what your question actually is-- is it "can I pass parameters in function calls?" because the answer is yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) does. For example:

```
other_function(callback=functools.partial(the_other_function, param1='foo', param2='bar'))
```